# Cannot use 'toJSON' with a sub model(using get method) of backbone.js relational model

Tags: backbone.js

I am new in backbone.js and struggling to find enough material to educate myself. My current problem is related to rendering Backbone relational model in to a template using underscore. My backbone relational model looks like this:

```
var stateReportBillModel = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
        urlRoot: 'rest/stateReportingBill',
        defaults:{
          relations: [
            {
                type: Backbone.HasMany,
                key: 'errors',
                relatedModel: 'errorModel',
                collectionType: 'errorCollection',
                includeInJSON: false,
                autoFetch: true
            },
            {
                type: Backbone.HasOne,
                key: 'claimInformation',
                relatedModel: 'claimInformationModel',
                includeInJSON: false,
                autoFetch: true
            },
            {
                type: Backbone.HasOne,
                key: 'billInformation',
                relatedModel: 'billInformationModel',
                includeInJSON: false,
                autoFetch:true
            },
            {
                type: Backbone.HasMany,
                key: 'lineItems',
                relatedModel: 'lineItemModel',
                collectionType: 'lineItemCollection',
                includeInJSON: false,
                autoFetch: true
            },
            {
                type: Backbone.HasOne,
                key: 'trackingInformation',
                relatedModel: 'trackingInformationModel',
                includeInJSON: false,
                autoFetch: true
            },
          ]
        },
        initialize: function(properties) {
            console.log('New StateReportingBill created');
        }
    });

  return stateReportBillModel;

});
```

After calling a successful RESTful get function I am trying to render the model in view using templates. With regular models I can pass the model to a template following way:

```
this.$el.append(this.errorsTemplate({
            errors: errors.toJSON(),
            errorTemplate: this.errorTemplate
      }));
```

But after retrieving the errors from the above mentioned model, if I try to pass the error model in this fashion I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'toJSON'
```

This is what I am trying to do

```
var errorsModel = this.model.get("errors");
this.$el.append(this.errorsTemplate({
   errors: errorsModel.toJSON(),
   errorTemplate: this.errorTemplate
}));
```

My errorsTemplate and errorTemplate looks like following:

```
<tbody>
<% _.each(errors, function(error) { %>
<%= errorTemplate(error) %>
<% }); %>
</tbody>
<tr>
    <td><%= message %></td>
    <td><%= type %></td>
    <td><%= value %></td>
    <td><%= formElement %></td>
    <td><%= lineNo %></td>
    <td><%= compoundSeqNumber %></td>
</tr>
```

I am assuming after getting a submodel from relational model I can't use toJSON like regular model. On the other hand if I call toJSON on the whole relational model it allows me to do so. If that is the case how can I pass the model to the templates. I don't want to pass the whole relational-model at a time to a big template rather get one sub-model at a time and pass them to different small templates. Any kind of help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If, after your "var errorsModel = this.model.get("errors");" line, you do a console.log(errorsModel), what does the browser think errorsModel is?

Comment: errorsModel: Object
errors: Array[2]
0: Object
1: Object
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
__proto__: Object

Comment: Oh, unless its a typo in putting the code into StackOverflow, it appears you have your relations array INSIDE your defaults hash.  It should not be.